# What will be URL rewrite in yii url manager

Tags: yii

I have already url rewrite

```
'compagnies' => 'site/compagnies',
```

I want to convert url which can accept format like

```
http://www.example.com/compagnies-abc-def.com
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/compagnies-kdlsfj.com
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/compagnies-fdsf_sdf
```

How can I write it in yii url manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
'compagnies-<identifier:.+>' => 'site/compagnies',
```

You will then be able to access the *identifier* value using `$_GET`, for example, if the URL is `compagnies-test` , you will be able to access the "test" portion of the url like so:

```
echo $_GET['identifier']; // echo's test
```