# Yii Url Manager(replace post_id with post_name)

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

I have completed a site in Yii.But the problem is site urls are not SEO friendly,and not finding its place in google searches .I have my urls as http://helll.com/Industries?id=1

i would like to change my urls to http://helll.com/Industries/hospitality-and-tourism ,ie,replacing the post id with the post name ,i already have a url rewrite like this

```
'/Industries'=>'/lriIndustries/See',
```

like here [What will be URL rewrite in yii url manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025830/what-will-be-url-rewrite-in-yii-url-manager) i have changed my url rewrite as follows but it seems to be not working

```
'/Industries-<industries_name:.+>'=>'/lriIndustries/See',
echo $_GET['industries_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot slash between Industries and industries_name.

```
'/Industries/<industries_name:.+>'=>'/lriIndustries/See',
```

You must also have urlMangager enabled with `urlFormat => 'path'` and actionSee($industries_name) in lriIndustriesController to get this work.

Why do you echo $_GET['industries_name'] everywhere?  You don't send any GET variables. Your $industries_name variable must be passed to actionSee like that (in lriIndustriesController).

```
public function actionSee($industries_name)
{
    //find Industry by name and show it
}
```

Comment: @V G i have my code for main.php here http://pastebin.com/uRSLjK8k vie w file herehttp://pastebin.com/y8CTDStw as it is showing some errors can you please review the code and help me thank you

Comment: @V G yes there are some errors 
Notice: Undefined index: industries_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LRI-Original/protected/config/main.php on line 3   ,here is my controller http://pastebin.com/wbGhz6Zx